# Updating Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-c++

I downloaded Microsoft Visual 2010 Express for Windows Phone, but now i want to have the Visual C++ in it for my project. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use C++ in Windows Phone 7 projects. You'll have to wait for Windows Phone 8 to be able to use C++.

Comment: No..my question is..Microsoft Visual 2010 Express for Windows Phone doesn't come with Visual C++. I need that

Comment: @SRI, VS 2010 Expres does not support Vis C++, Microsoft has decided that   :-)